# create pivot table with 2 dimensions

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, postgres-14

I have 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE loans
(
    loan_id int,
    client_id int,
    loan_date date
);

CREATE TABLE clients
(
    client_id int,
    client_name varchar(20),
    gender varchar(20)
);

INSERT INTO CLIENTS
VALUES (1, arnold, 'male'),
       (2, lilly, 'female'),
       (3, betty, 'female'),
       (4, tom, 'male'),
       (5, jim, 'male');

INSERT INTO loans
VALUES (1, 1, '20220522'),
       (2, 2, '20220522'),
       (3, 3, '20220525'),
       (4, 4, '20220525'),
       (5, 1, '20220527'),
       (6, 2, '20220527'),
       (7, 3, '20220601'),
       (8, 1, '20220603'),
       (9, 2, '20220603'),
       (10, 1, '20220603');
```

It is necessary to calculate by years the number of contracts for loans in the context of the serial number of the contract and sex.

Output should be:

| sex | 1 contract, 2022 | 2 contract, 2022 | 3 contract, 2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| male | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| female | 4 | 1 | 1 |

1 contract, 2 contract - Its client contract serial number.

Probably need to apply crosstab here, but it does not apply to CTE.

I would like to have auto-completion of the serial number and year in the columns, because the period includes several years and a large number of contracts

```
with cte as 
(
    select 
        l.client_id,
        loan_date,
        extract(year from loan_date) as year,
        client_name,
        gender,
        row_number() over (partition by l.client_id order by loan_date asc) as serial_number_contact
    from 
        loans l
    inner join 
        clientc on l.client_id = c.client_id
)
select 
    gender,
    year,
    serial_number_contact,
    count(*) as count_loan
from
    cte
group by 
    gender, year, serial_number_contact
order by 
    serial_number_contact, year
```

Comment: I've removed the conflicting tags here; SQL Server 2008 (which has been completely unsupported for well over 3 years)  isn't a version of PostgreSQL. Please [edit] your question to (re)tag the (R)DBMS and it's version.

Answer (score 0):

```
;with cte as(
select gender,
row_number() over (partition by l.client_id order by l.client_id,l.loan_date) serial
from loans l 
    inner join clients c
        on c.client_id=l.client_id)

        select gender
            ,sum(case when serial=1 then 1 else 0 end) as "1 Contract 2022"
            ,sum(case when serial=2 then 1 else 0 end) as "2 Contract 2022"
            ,sum(case when serial=3 then 1 else 0 end) as "3 Contract 2022"
        from cte group by gender
```

### Test

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0d0b93/3

Comment: @ Horaciux I would like to have auto-completion of the serial number and year in the columns, because the period includes several years and a large number of contracts

Comment: You'll need a dynamic query for that